# What does font size really mean in ios?

Tags: ios, core-text, uifont, typography, textkit

Seems font size doesn't determine anything.

Here is two line, one use font `zapfino`, another use `system font`. They both has size 30, but the line height or other font metrics is really different.
[image: Here is the pic]

*This pic is draw with [YYLabel](https://github.com/ibireme/YYText) which use `coretext` layout and draw the text, use this framework we can easily see the border of one glyph.*

Below is another pic which use two `UILabel` with different font and preview it in `StroyBoard`.
[image]

So what does font size mean in `coretext` when layout one line?

Comment: What sort of UI control is that?  Looks to me like it's performing some sort of auto-fill behaviour which would obviously negate the font size...

Comment: [YYLabel](https://github.com/ibireme/YYText) 
@Droppy, but when we try this with a `UILabel`, it's behave the same.

Comment: OK... so as to the rest of my question... what attributes are you setting that would cause it to auto-fill height or whatever?

Comment: I have edit the question and attach a pic use two `UILabel` to illustrate the difference,@Droppy

Comment: Yeah you're still avoiding the issue however.  That label has some functionality relating to auto-sizing and until you reveal what attributes you are using, no-one can answer your question.  `UILabel` also has auto-sizing behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean auto-sizing, it's just a `instrinsicContentSize` of the label?@Droppy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) for *point (typography)*:

> When a point size of a font is specified, the font is scaled so that its em square has a side length of that particular length in points. Although the letters of a font usually fit within the font's em square, there is not necessarily any size relationship between the two, so the point size does not necessarily correspond to any measurement of the size of the letters[.]

So in all digital fonts, the font-size doesn't really correlate with anything except an imaginary square the font designer chose to design their glyphs on top of. So sometimes this will correlate with the width of the capital M, but not always. And *Zapfino*, the font you mentioned, is one of the more audacious examples of totally overshooting its boundary boxes. Here it is next to Helvetica, at the same point size:

[image]

Although they have a similar X-height, Zapfino's cap-height, ascenders, and descenders are so large that each letter's cell height in most rendering engines, including CoreText, will be more than twice that of Helvetica. It's simply how the font was designed. You'll either need to manually fit your font-size depending on which typeface you use, or try a programmatic approach like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468641/calculate-font-size-to-fit-frame-core-text-nsattributedstring-ios).

Good luck!

Comment: So when layout a line, a render engine will use the letter's cell height? What 's this cell height mean in the font?

Comment: What tool do you use to compare the two font?

Comment: Most render engines (including all browsers I'm aware of) calculate the glpyh's cell height as the distance from the descender line to the ascender line (the lowercase "f" in my Zapfino example extends the length of it).

Comment: And I used Photoshop to create my example.